# When doing a change of variables integration, what does a jacobian (determinant) of 0 tell us?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, change-of-variable

Given a change of variables $x = f(u, v), y = g(u, v)$ if we get that $\partial(x, y)/\partial(u, v) = det [\begin{matrix} \partial x/\partial u & \partial x/\partial v \\ \partial y/\partial u & \partial y / \partial v \end{matrix}] = 0$. What does that tell us?

Idea: in single variable calculus, a determinant of $0$ tells us that the function is constant. So is the idea similar here? Naively asking the two variable function to be constant seems to be obviously false, so I'm wondering if it means something weaker such as being constant on a surface/area instead? And in the specific case of change of variables, how do we intepret this?

Comment: It means the change of variables is uninvertible, usually because of the loss of a degree of freedom e.g. a 2-manifold being mapped to a 1-manifold.

Comment: What bothers me is that if I'm doing an integration problem and I change my variables into something uninvertible as you say, I would get an integral of 0 regardless of my domain. That doesn't seem right; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yea, such a Jacobian is not a valid change of variable for that purpose. A change of variables must always be invertible (almost everywhere)

Comment: Oh I see, that actually clears up another doubt I was having. Thank you!

Comment: I added an important caveat, have a look. It is alright for change of variables to not be invertible on sets of measure zero. Polar coordinates is the most obvious example of such a change of variables.